# Is there a workaround for this bug with how Swift handles protocols?

Tags: swift, protocols

The compiler won't compile the below code, because it brokenly claims:

> Protocol type `Fooesque` cannot conform to `Fooesque` because only concrete types can conform to protocols.

```swift
protocol Fooesque { var bar: Int { get set } }
class FooStruct: Fooesque { var bar = 42 }
struct Bar<F: Fooesque> {
    typealias MyFoo = F
    var foo: MyFoo
    init(foo: MyFoo) { self.foo = foo }
}
struct Whee {
    var someSpecificFoo: Fooesque
    func process() { let bar = Bar(foo: someSpecificFoo) } // error line
}
var whee = Whee(someSpecificFoo: FooStruct())
```

Obviously this is a bug, because `someSpecificFoo` is already declared as a concrete instance that conforms to `Fooesque` (that's what `var someSpecificFoo: Fooesque` *means)*.

If we try to fix by changing it to, `var someSpecificFoo: some Fooesque`, now the buggy compiler will say:

> Property declares an opaque return type, but has no initializer expression from which to infer an underlying type

Now, not only will it fail to auto-synthesize an initializer expression like normal, but it will also fail even if we add one manually. Adding:

```swift
    init<F: Fooesque>(foo: F) { self.foo = foo }
```

... does not fix anything—it just changes the buggy error message to:

> Cannot assign value of type `F` to type `some Fooesque`

... even though F conforms to Fooesque! So broken!

Has anyone found a workaround for this mess?

So far the only fix I've found is to simply add `@objc` to the first line and `import Foundation`, in which case, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Swift compiler expert but I don't think that this is true.

> Obviously this is a bug, because someSpecificFoo is already declared as a concrete instance that conforms to Fooesque (that's what var someSpecificFoo: Fooesque means).

It seems like the problem is exactly that. There is nothing concrete about that declaration. It could be anything that conforms to Fooesque. When you create a Bar with `F` as the protocol `Fooesque` you're saying `Fooesque` should conform to `Fooesque` which it cannot do. Only concrete types can do that.

If you change the line to `var someSpecificFoo: FooStruct` then it seems to work. But maybe that's not what you're going for.

Not sure what you're actually trying to do because these types are all so made up but maybe a more specific example would help?

Cheers!

Comment: "When you create a Bar with F as the protocol Fooesque you're saying Fooesque should conform to Fooesque which it cannot do"

That's not at all what this code says:
`init<F: Fooesque>(foo: F) { self.foo = foo }`

This means that the generic type F *conforms to Fooesque*. It doesn't mean that it *is* Fooesque. Also, I'm not doing `self.foo = F` here, I'm just doing `self.foo = foo` where `foo` is of type `F` which conforms to `Fooesque`, and that is the only requirement of the variable with type `some Fooesque`.

Comment: I agree with you that that code means that.You're essentially "passing in" Fooesque as F when you call the initializer with someSpecificFoo. someSpecificFoo is doesn't have a concrete type (that the compiler knows about) so it has no way to know what type F should be. F can't be a protocol, it has to be a concrete type.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a buggy compiler; it's rather your misunderstanding of generics constraints.

`Bar` is a generic type that can be concretized with a specific type that conforms to `Fooesque`.

For example, you could have a `Bar<FooStruct>` type. This concrete type has the following init declaration:

```
init(foo: FooStruct)
```

`Bar<FooStruct>` does not accept just any type conforming to `Fooesque` - it **only** accepts `FooStruct`.

And it is explicitly **NOT** `init(foo: Fooesque)`, but you expected it to behave as such, by conceptually doing the following:

```
let f: Fooesque = ...
let bar = Bar(foo: f)
```

What's the concrete type of Bar would you expect above?

The compiler infers `F` to be `Fooesque` based on the type of the argument, so it attempts to create a concrete type `Bar<Fooesque>`, which fails, because `Fooesque` - being a protocol - doesn't conform to other protocols, including itself.

---

But you'd probably say, no, I don't want the generic type to be a `Fooesque`; I want some type conforming to `Fooesque`.

Ok, which one? Let's say, it's `FooStruct` in the example above:

```
let f: Fooesque = ....
let bar = Bar<FooStruct>(foo: f) // ERROR
```

Again error, because `Bar<FooStruct>` expects a `FooStruct` as an argument - not any `Fooesque`.

Similarly, if you had `AnotherFooStruct: Fooesque`, then you would have a `Bar<AnotherFooStruct>` type, expecting `AnotherFooStruct` as an argument.

And thus - similarly - if you had any (generic) `F` type - aliased as `MyFoo`, in your example - then `Bar<MyFoo>` would only accept a `MyFoo` type - not `Fooesque`.

What that `MyFoo` type is, is determined at *compile-time*, either explicitly or implicitly based on the static type of the passed in parameter.

Comment: `It is explicitly NOT init(foo: Fooesque)` That's not what I expected it to be. However I should be able to call `init(foo: MyFoo)` on `Bar` with a value of type `Fooesque` since `MyFoo` is just a typealias to `F: Fooesque`. Any `someSpecificFoo: Fooesque` is, under the hood, a `FooStruct` (as that's the only possibility in my example) so when I'd call `Bar(foo: someSpecificFoo)` then it should create an instance of `Bar<FooStruct>` instead of not compiling.

Comment: "...since `MyFoo` is just a typealias to `F: Fooesque`..."... - the key part here is that **`MyFoo` is a typealias to `F`** - a generic type, which becomes something like a `FooStruct`...  Generics are a compile-time determination. The type has to be known at compile-time, which in your case is only know as an existential `Fooesque`